# Objective -c:How to print a big digit from a number

Tags: string, nsstring

I have a string

```
NSString * numberString=@"6384";
```

How do I print the  largest digit from the string

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the help center, in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What part are you stuck on? What have you tried? Right now, the question reads like "please write code for me to do this" which presumably isn't what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should get you started:

```
NSUInteger i;
unichar max = 0;

for (i = 0; i < [numberString length]; i++)
    if (max < [numberString characterAtIndex: i])
        max = [numberString characterAtIndex: i];
return max;
```

Comment: Can u explain max is not getting incremented right how it is checking